# Why does self variable lose value after method invocation

Tags: python

I have this code to implement queue and stack data structures. The `QueueT` by itself works as desired.

When I call `st.push(1)`, it agreeable calls `push(self, v)` and this in turn calls the `enqueue` method.

The issue I am facing is that after the statement `self._q1.enqueue(v)` is executed, `self._q1` does not retain the value `v`.

Code for class `QueueT`:

```
class QueueT:
    def __init__(self):
        self._CAPACITY = 6
        self._data = [None] * self._CAPACITY
        self._length = 0
        self._first = 0

    def enqueue(self, val):
        if self.size() == self._CAPACITY:
            self._resize(self._CAPACITY * 2)
            self.enqueue(val)
        else:
            new_place = (self._first + self.size()) % self._CAPACITY
            self._data[new_place] = val
            self._length += 1

    def size(self):
        return self._length

    def _resize(self, new_capacity):
        old = self._data
        old_capacity = len(old)
        self._data = [None] * new_capacity
        k = self._first
        self._first = 0
        for j in range(self._length):
            self._data[j] = old[k]
            k = (1 + k) % old_capacity
        self._CAPACITY = new_capacity
```

Now code from `StackFromQ`:

```
class StackFromQ:
    def __init__(self):
        self._q1 = QueueT()
        self._top = -1

    def push(self, v):
        self._q1.enqueue(v)
        self._top += 1
```

Caller function:

```
def stack_of_q():
    st = StackFromQ()
    st.push(1)
    st.push(2)
```

Finally invocation:

```
stack_of_q()
```

Comment: What makes you think that `self._q1` does not retain the value `v`?

Comment: This code works for me. After running `stack_of_q()` the data is [1, 2, None, ...]

Comment: As I debug through the code, I do not see _q1 accumulating the values. Thast the reason for his post.